# AI Boolean is giving me a jagged edge

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I booleaned a circle and the top portion with the pen tool for a keychain to be laser engraved, I am not liking the edge cut at this location and suspect this could be the problem.  Is this normal?[image]

Comment: Two points on top of each other. Amyway, you should use a round miter as it reflects much better how the laser behaves.

Answer (score 3):

You have a twist in the edge curve:

[image]

In the left the handles are long. When they are dragged shorter, the right version is generated.

Here's another unlucky version: A twist and miter corner join - long peaks are generated easily:

[image]

**A fix:** Make the anchor a corner point by clicking it with the anchor type tool (it's under the pen) If you need a soft curve, then drag with the same tool starting from the anchor. Drag to the right direction, otherwise you get a new twist.

Give the last touch with the direct selection tool.

**A twist can stay unnoticed** as long as there's round or bevel curve corner join in use (the type can be selected in the strokes panel). In boolean operations the type is inherited from one of the objects (the topmost one) and an old twist can pop visible.

Comment: That or there are 2points on top of eachother. In either case wont affect the laser cutter because its following the center so having a round miter better reflects what the laser does.